# Can Thunar's "Places" list be re-ordered?

Tags: shortcuts, xfce, thunar

Thunar has a list on the side of the display, titled "Places". By default, it includes shortcuts to Home, Desktop, Recent, Documents, and many more. How can I reorder this list of shortcuts?

Comment: I use Thunar fairly frequently. The Thunar side page options do not permit the reorder of places